# The ObjectInstance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use EF6. In my BL-Layer I have following static class, working with my context, which implements DBContext:

```
 public static class AppEnvironment
 {
        public static IUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
        private static IKernel AppKernel { get; set; }

    public static void InjectDependencies(params NinjectModule[] contextNinjectModule)
    {
        AppKernel = new StandardKernel(contextNinjectModule);
    }

    public static void Authorize(string login, string password)
    {
        using (var context = AppKernel.Get<ICaseContext>())
        {
            IUser userToBeAuthorized = context.GetAll<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == login);

            if (userToBeAuthorized != null && User.GetMD5Hash(password) == userToBeAuthorized.PasswordHash)
            {
                AppEnvironment.CurrentUser = userToBeAuthorized;

                context.Insert(
                    LogRecord.CreateLogRecord(
                    userToBeAuthorized,
                    "Авторизация (успешно)",
                    LogAction.Read));
            }

        }
    }

    public static ICollection<CaseEntityType> GetCaseListTiny<CaseEntityType>(string queryComment) where CaseEntityType : CaseEntityBase
    {
        using (var context = AppKernel.Get<ICaseContext>())
        {
            var grantedCaseTypesIDs = AppEnvironment.CurrentUser.CaseTypesGranted.Select(casetype => casetype.ID).ToList();
            var cases = context.GetAllIncluding<TaskEntityType>(AppEnvironment.CurrentUser, queryComment, LogAction.Read, t => t.CaseType
                ).Where(t => grantedTaskTypesIDs.Contains(t.CaseType.ID)).ToList();
            return cases;
        }
    }
}
```

In my UI Layer I'm trying to use smth like that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppEnvironment.InjectDependencies(new RealContextNinjectModule());
        AppEnvironment.Authorize("UserName", "Password");
        var caseList = AppEnvironment.GetCaseListTiny<RegularCase>("Get a list");
        foreach (var item in caseList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws ObjectContextDisposedException. Can anybody explain what's the right way of dealing with EF6 context class? How should I use it in my BLL or UIL? Why I'm not allowed to use my context class again, after it has been disposed once? I've read a lot of similar questions, but everybody says only smth about eager/lazy loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that "everybody says only smth about eager/lazy loading" is because that is what is happening. The sequence of events is:

```
var caseList = AppEnvironment.GetCaseListTiny<RegularCase>("Get a list");
```

GetCaseTinyList then calls AppKernel.Get which returns the context into a local *var context* wrapped up in a *using* block. Within the block, it created a collection by issuing a call against the context. It does not access that list, and so the collection is not in fact populated; no SQL is run until the collection is accessed. This is lazy eveluation.

At the end of the using block, it disposes of the *context*. This closes the database connection and marks the context object as disposed and thus unusable.

GetCaseTinyList returns, passing the unpopulated collection back.

Finally, you run a foreach against the returned collection. At the first access the EF collection tries to run the SQL for the GetCaseTinyList against the context. Sadly, the context has been disposed (you did tell it to dispose it and so it did). This makes the system throw the error you are getting, exactly as it should.

One way you can get around this is to change GetCaseTinyCollection to access the collection; something like this:

```
public static ICollection<CaseEntityType> GetCaseListTiny<CaseEntityType>(string queryComment) where CaseEntityType : CaseEntityBase
{
    using (var context = AppKernel.Get<ICaseContext>())
    {
        var grantedCaseTypesIDs = AppEnvironment.CurrentUser.CaseTypesGranted.Select(casetype => casetype.ID).ToList();
        var cases = context.GetAllIncluding<TaskEntityType>(AppEnvironment.CurrentUser, queryComment, LogAction.Read, t => t.CaseType
            ).Where(t => grantedTaskTypesIDs.Contains(t.CaseType.ID)).ToList();
        int count = cases.Count(); // or Count<T>();
        return cases;
    }
}
```

This will force the collection to be populated before the context is disposed. However it may have further shortcomings: if the entities in the collection have in turn collection of other objects then when accessed it will try to populate these sub-collections and you're back where you are now.

Another approach is not to use a using/dispose pattern. But at some point you are going to have to clean up the context so you'll have to think about how to do this.

Also, it's far easier when inserting/updating EF entities to keep the context around which you used to read the data. If you don't you have to transfer the updated entities to a new context which sounds like a pain (I've never done it that way).

Basically, you need to rethink your strategy for managing the database context.

Comment: So, can you show me the way to select correct strategy for managing DBContext? I'm really frustrated with it :(

Comment: And, the most interesting for me is: can I create context again, when it's been already disposed?

Comment: You can. But if you make changes to an object got from the first one and then call SaveChanges() on the second, the second doesn't know about changes made to the first. You must a) keep the context alive for the durstion of the transaction (select to SaveChanges) or b) use newContext.Attach(changedObject) to attach changed objects to  the new context; I've never used it so I'm not at all sure of the syntax.